# classic asp sending email

Tags: email, asp-classic

is it possible to send email without cdo and else installed dlls?

Comment: i need WITHOUT install any dll

Comment: Sorry, I misread it. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use any DLL to send email, I think the only solution would be to **make a call from you ASP to an external mail server** that would be responsible for the sending of the emails. You could use an HTTP post to accomplish it.

On your server, your code should look like:

```
Dim url, httpBroker
url = "http://mail.yourdomain/send.asp" 
Set httpBroker = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
httpBroker.open "POST", url, false 
httpBroker.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
httpBroker.send "to=name@gmail.com&body=<html><body>Hello!</body></html>" 
Response.write httpBroker.responseText 
Set httpBroker = Nothing
```

On the mail server, `send.asp` will be responsible to send the email using a DLL installed on the server or CDONTS. **This solution would only work if you have another server with the required DLL installed**.

Now, if you don't have another server at your disposal, you should have a look at the API of the mail engine installed on your server. If are using [Mail Enable](http://www.mailenable.com/), there exists a **pickup directory in which emails to send can be dropped for processing**. But it all depends on the software you are running.

Comment: any sample with external mail server ?